# Converting SQL queries from PostGIS to BigQuery

Tags: sql, carto, google-big-query

I have a table called drawn_items with columns “the_geom”, “fsrn_db” , & “area” in Carto2 which is queried by SQL. Having recreated the table in Carto 3, in order to use the query, I must translate it from postGIS to Bigquery. “the geom” changes to “geom” and I think ST_GeomFromGeoJSON changes to ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON. An access token must be concatenated to the end of the string and I know this is working from testing on another query.

SQL Query in postGIS for Carto 2 (working)

```
"INSERT INTO drawn_items (the_geom, fsrn_db, area) " + 
                        "VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + 
                        drawing + "'), 4326), '" + 
                        enteredFSRN + "', '" +
                        seeArea2 + "')";
```

Attempt at SQL Query in Bigquery for Carto 3

```
let sql = 
                        "INSERT INTO shared.drawn_items (geom, fsrn_db, area) " + 
                        "VALUES (ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('" + 
                        drawing + "'), '" + 
                        enteredFSRN + "', '" +
                        seeArea2 + "')"+access_token;
```

However, this does not work and I get a 400 error.

How should it be structured?

[image]

[image]

The location of the error referenced above as 1:215 is the first pair of coordinates, so it seems to me that ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON is not translating the geoJSON into BigQuery properly?

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests the problem is not related to GeoJson at all.

It says "Value has type **STRING** which cannot be inserted into column **area**, which has type **BIGNUMERIC**"

Highlights:

1. you have a column named **area** of type **BIGNUMERIC**
2. let's see what we are trying to insert into it
3. it is `'" + seeArea2 + "'` - quoted **seeArea2** value
4. due to quotes this value is of type **STRING**, which cannot be inserted into BIGNUMERIC column

Most likely you just need to remove the quotes around **seeArea2**. Not likely, but depending on what is there you might also need to cast it to BIGNUMERIC some way.

P.S. bigquery is normally supported in StackOverflow, not GIS StackExchange, tag [google-bigquery].

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately removing the quotation marks did not eliminate the 400 error “missing query parameter” when the query is executed in leaflet. 
When I paste the query manually into a browser address bar it does add a record to the Carto 3 database although it hides all other records in the data preview screen.

Comment: Looks like a completely new error, that is Carto-specific. You probably had two completely separate issues, the "Value ... cannot be inserted" from BigQuery that I explained, and Missing parameter error from Carto API that I cannot help with.